# Add WMS to OpenLayers after click

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms, node-js

I have a working WMS service under `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nis/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nis%3Atest`

Also I have a Node JS application with OpenLayers. In this application I have a button. It gets visible after a certain condition is met. With this button I want the user to be able to load the WMS.

This is my button:

```
          </button>
      <label
        className={this.state.addMessageVisible ? "sc-fakeLink" : "sc-hidden"}
        style={{ gridColumnStart: "1", gridColumnEnd: "3", gridRowStart: "4", textAlign: "-webkit-center", alignSelf: "center" }}
        onMouseUp={this.onAddWMSToMyMaps}
      >
        Show WMS
      </label>
```

This is triggered by the button:

```
  onAddWMSToMyMaps = () => {
// ADD MYMAPS
window.emitter.emit("addWMS");};
```

which in turn triggers this on the map canvas:

```
    window.emitter.addListener("addWMS",() => this.addLayerviaWMS(true));}
```

and after all shall trigger this one:

```
  addLayerviaWMS = () => {
var newlayer = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nis/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nis%3Atest4733'
window.map.addLayer(newlayer)};
```

The error is the following:

```
TypeError: can't assign to property "ol_uid" on "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nis/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nis%3Atest4733": not an object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newlayer` is assigned to a string, the OpenLayers `addLayer()` method expects an OpenLayers layer object

```
  var newlayer = new ImageLayer({
    source: new ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nis/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'nis:test4733'},
      ratio: 1,
      serverType: 'geoserver'
    });
```

see this example  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image.html

Comment: thanks for that push in the right direction! worked!